# Can't flag a duplicates a second time. What should be done on my end

Tags: discussion, specific-question, flagging, closing

A while ago I noticed a question was a duplicate and so marked it as one using the flagging option. The other question had recently received an answer and I am pretty sure I up voted it, but I may have been the only up voter. The questions are asked in a very similar way so I think any one looking for that question and came across one would also come across the other. The "duplicate" is not showing up as a duplicate. Now there are two answers to the question I did not flag, one of them with 9 up votes and was also accepted.

What should be done? Should I leave it since it seems the community did not agree that it was a duplicate? Should I flag it for moderators attention? Should I come to meta and tell people to close a question as duplicate? Should I gain 1700 points and maybe have the powers to close it?

What is the most likely reason the question I marked as duplicate was not determined to be a duplicate?

Edit:
The post I marked duplicate is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134410/show-that-the-group-is-trivial) and the one I did not is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023341/presentation-of-group-equal-to-trivial-group).

Comment: It will help to sort the situation out if you included a link to the post you think is a duplicate, and a link to the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your close-flag sent the post into Close Review. You can see the result of review [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/349074). The majority of reviewers decided to leave the question open. Not sure why; it does look like a duplicate to me. I voted to close as a duplicate now. [Update: closed].

---

In the future, if you think the reviewers made a mistake, feel free to drop a message in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/reopen-undelete-close-delete) for "sorting things out when the usual review process does not work".